# Rails - Soulmate, export to json one item per line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rake, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use Soulmate to make the search and autocompletion. However it requires a json file with all data under a model and one item per line. When I export with to_json i get all object separated by comma.

This is what I want to print:

```
{"id":1,"term":"Dodger Stadium","score":85,"data":{"url":"\/dodger-stadium-tickets\/","subtitle":"Los Angeles, CA"}}
{"id":28,"term":"Angel Stadium","score":85,"data":{"url":"\/angel-stadium-tickets\/","subtitle":"Anaheim, CA"}}
{"id":30,"term":"Chase Field ","score":85,"data":{"url":"\/chase-field-tickets\/","subtitle":"Phoenix, AZ"}}
{"id":29,"term":"Sun Life Stadium","score":84,"data":{"url":"\/sun-life-stadium-tickets\/","subtitle":"Miami, FL"}}
{"id":2,"term":"Turner Field","score":83,"data":{"url":"\/turner-field-tickets\/","subtitle":"Atlanta, GA"}}
```

And this is what I print with to_json

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Philip","last_name":"nalle","location":"nallemia","email":"hejsan@hej.com","active":false,"created_at":"2013-06-26T15:00:38.990Z","updated_at":"2013-06-26T15:00:38.990Z"},{"id":2,"first_name":"Philip","last_name":"nalle","location":"hejsan123","email":"hejsan@asd.com","active":false,"created_at":"2013-06-26T15:01:45.905Z","updated_at":"2013-06-26T15:01:45.905Z"},{"id":3,"first_name":"hejsan","last_name":"hejsan","location":"asd","email":"asd@asda.com","active":false,"created_at":"2013-06-26T15:08:20.354Z","updated_at":"2013-06-26T15:08:20.354Z"},{"id":4,"first_name":"well well","last_name":"hello","location":"asd123","email":"asd@asd.com","active":false,"created_at":"2013-06-26T15:10:27.121Z","updated_at":"2013-06-26T15:12:29.991Z"}]
```

Don't mind the actual data inside the json, I just copied a sample from soulmates readme. This is the rake task.

```
desc "Save all participants to json"
task :save_to_json => :environment do
    File.open("participants.json", "w") { |f| f.write(Participant.all.to_json)} 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to output elements one by one.
It will also save memory if instead of .all you grab them by 1000 if there are many of them.

```
desc "Save all participants to json"
task :save_to_json => :environment do
    File.open("participants.json", "w") do |f| 
        Participant.all.each do |participant| 
            f.write("#{participant.to_json}\n")
        end
    end
end
```